# Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider.. Spring-boot on the backend

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am wiring AngularJS with Spring-boot. My Rest Controller is rendering the index.html file in my webApps folder but my  is not rendering the "Home" page I have set up.

index.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="app/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  Test Test Test

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src=""></script>
  <script src="app/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <script src="app/components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/home/homeConfig.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/home/homeController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js
    angular.module('myApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'myApp.version'
    ]);

homeConfig.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('home',{
                parent: 'site',
                url: '/',
                data: {
                    roles: []
                },

                views: {
                    'content@:':{
                        templateUrl: 'app/scripts/home/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController'
                    }
                }

            });

}]);
```

HomeController.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller("HomeController",['$scope', function($scope){

        console.log("Inside the HomeController")

    }]);
```

home.html

```
<div>
    <h2>You have landed on the home page!!!</h2>
</div>
```

I have spring-boot on the back end.

IndexController.java

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        System.out.println("Looking in the index controller.........");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Currently what is rendering it "Test Test Test" which is written on index.html. I am looking for "You have landed on the home page!!!"

full error displayed in console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
```

[image: Directory]

-----------------SOLUTION---------------

Use routeProvider and not $stateProvider

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/scripts/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stateProvider` is part of [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), not the native angular router. In your case, you should be using `$routeProvider` and the `$routeProvider.when` syntax instead of `$stateProvider.state`. Documentation on `$routerProvider` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).